# How to get count of substring in string using regular expressions?

Tags: php

I have a string and format of substring, for example "Hello world!%1, abcdef%2, gfgf%14", i.e. format of substring is '%'+digit (0...infinity), and I need to get count of this substring in any string. I know about substring_count function, but for this function I need to know a defined line. So, please, tell me, how can I get count using regular expressions or anything else?

EDITED:

THis code works:

```
$r = "Hello world!%1, abcdef%2, gfgf%14";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\%\d+/', $r, $matches);
echo isset($matches[0]) ? count($matches[0]) : 0;
```

But if I have a space before %1 or after it, the code doesn't work. Please, fix this expression. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "defined line"? Is your input string multiline, and yo want to know the line number of every matched occurance?

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried.

Comment: I mean that for substring_count() I must input "%1" or anything else for searching, but I know only format - "%"+digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use preg_match_all with $matches array (third parameter) and then calculate length or array of occurences:

```
$r = "Hello world!%1, abcdef%2, gfgf%14";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\%\d+/', $r, $matches);
echo isset($matches[0]) ? count($matches[0]) : 0;
```

Comment: One thing, please - modify your expression for spaces for left and right, for example "give me %1 and %2"

Comment: do you mean spaces must be present on both sides or may be present? current script says that "give me %1 and %2" has 2 occurences.

Comment: @Truth has the correct code. You don't need to count the results because `preg_match_all` returns the number of matches.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$str = "Hello world!%1, abcdef%2, gfgf%14";

$match_count = preg_match_all("/%\d+/", $str);

echo $match_count;
```

By the way, `$matches` will hold all of the matched substrings.

Answer (score 0):

If you will never you use the % sign for anything other than defining a substring in my mind the easiest way is to do this:

```
$pieces = explode('%',$string);
$num_substrings = count($pieces) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all` returns the number of matches.

```
$r = "Hello world!%1, abcdef%2, gfgf%14";
echo preg_match_all('/\%\d+/', $r, $matches);
// in PHP >= 5.4 you can leave out $matches
```

Result:

```
3
```